# keyerror python

Tags: python, массивы

не понимаю в чем проблема.
Библиотека request импортированна.
Вот код который не работает

```
routes = requests.get(SERVICE + origin + destination + waypoints).json()
```

`geometry = [decode(section) for section in routes['routes'][0]['sections']]`
Выдает ошибку KeyError: 'routes'

Comment: выложите то, что прилетает в routes

Comment: Ну значит нет там элемента с таким ключом